# How to manipulate a function within a lambda with python?

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'd like to manipulate a list of lambda functions. This list of lambda functions all contain the same function within it, which I'd like to manipulate so that the function within it has an additional argument

See below for my example

```
def base_function(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

list_of_functions = [
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_1'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_2'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_3')
]
```

Is it possible to change this list of functions to the following without having to re-write the entire list of functions

```
list_of_functions = [
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_1','another_arg'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_2','another_arg'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_3','another_arg')
]
```

See below for another example of what I'm trying to do. I have the below:

```
def simple_function(arg,capitalize=False):
    if capitalize:
        print arg.upper()
    else:
        print arg 


list_of_functions = [lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word),lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word)]
```

But I would like to change list_of_functions to the following without having to re-write either list_of_functions above or simple_function:

```
desired_list_of_functions = [lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word,capitalize=True),lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word,capitalize=True)]
```

Comment: Will the calls always be to the same function? You could maintain a list of lists (of args), and then map them to function calls at the last minute. Alternatively, you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.partial#functools.partial) and maybe manipulate the `partial.args` (same documentation) of the resulting objects?

Comment: In my scenario yes the calls will be to the same function. But even if each item in a list refers to a different function, I'd still like to be able to add an additional function to each function within the list if possible.

Comment: If you're going to support different functions, you'll probably want to take the `partial` approach.

Comment: From taking a quick look at the documentation, I agree as its very relevant. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to apply to my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's how I'd do it using partial application, as suggested by @austin-hastings:

```
# first example from the OP

def base_function(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

list_of_functions = [
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_1'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_2'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_3')
]

# solution:

from functools import partial

new_list_of_functions = [
  partial(fn, 'another_arg') for fn in list_of_functions
]
```

to place the argument at the end, you can have a look at [@austin-hastings's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43618965/1290438).

---

of course you can shadow list_of_functions with your partial application.

then, for your given use case:

```
desired_list_of_functions = [
  lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word,capitalize=True),
  lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word,capitalize=True)
]
```

you can do the application that way:

```
desired_list_of_functions = [
    partial(fn, capitalize=True) for fn in list_of_functions
]
```

that's because `partial` takes as arguments `(fn, *args, **kwargs)` which will be applied to the function.

---

ok, a work around for your problem can be done as follows, by using reference shadowing:

```
def simple_function(arg,capitalize=False):
    if capitalize:
        print (arg.upper())
    else:
        print (arg)


list_of_functions = [lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word),lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word)]

# will print 'foo' twice
for fn in list_of_functions:
    fn('foo')

simple_function = partial(simple_function, capitalize=True)

# will print 'FOO' twice
for fn in list_of_functions:
    fn('foo')
```

the above hack takes advantage of the fact that the `lambda` definitions in `list_of_functions` is not yet bound to the `simple_function` reference, as the content of the lambda function hasn't been executed at runtime.

The reference is being valued only when the lambda is being called, so the `simple_function` reference within the lambda will point to the new partial instance instead of the original function instance.

Comment: but if you do `for fn in list_of_functions`, then `fn` is already a lambda function which does not accept keyword arguments?

Comment: ah good note and my bad, I missed that detail  let me give it a thought and complete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

a bit dirty solution could be as follows:

```
def simple_function(arg, capitalize=False):
    if capitalize:
        print arg.upper()
    else:
        print arg

#this function takes as its argument a lambda function which
#is assumed to merely call another global function defined within
#the same module  
def transf(l):
    #find out which function is being called from within the lambda
    f = globals()[l.__code__.co_names[0]]

    #return a lambda calling the same function with customized keyword argument
    return lambda arg: f(arg, capitalize=True)

list_of_functions = [lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word),lambda key_word: simple_function(key_word)]

new_list_of_functions = list(map(transf, list_of_functions))

for f in list_of_functions:
    f('x')

for f in new_list_of_functions:
    f('x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that subclasses `partial` so as to put the pre-specified args at the back. It starts with the code you provided, and then replaces it (mainly so I could confirm the behavior):

```
def base_function(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg

list_of_functions = [
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_1'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_2'),
    lambda new_arg: base_function(new_arg,'arg_3')
]

for f in list_of_functions:
    f('x')

import functools

class partial_atend(functools.partial):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f=self.func
        args += self.args
        kw = self.keywords.copy()
        kw.update(kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kw)

list_of_functions = [
    partial_atend(base_function, 'arg_1'),
    partial_atend(base_function, 'arg_2'),
    partial_atend(base_function, 'arg_3'),
]

# Modify args:
list_of_functions = [ partial_atend(f.func, *(f.args+('another_arg',)), **f.keywords) for f in list_of_functions]

# Make the call:
print "Make the call(s)..."
for f in list_of_functions:
    f('x')
```

One thing worth noting: I didn't want to mess around with possibly having partials calling partial_atends calling ... whatever. So I chose to expand the arguments in the list comprehension, and then replace one partial object with a new partial object. This will be faster (if that matters), and I think it's a little less likely to be gummed up by any implementation details.

**EDIT:**

To address the `capitalize=True` update, you could do the same thing with the [`keywords`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools.partial#functools.partial.keywords) attribute:

First, modify the `base_function` to print kwargs:

```
def base_function(*args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        print arg
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        print("{}={}".format(k,v))
```

Then, append this code:

```
# Modify kwargs, add `capitalize=True`:
list_of_functions = [ partial_atend(f.func, *f.args, capitalize=True, **f.keywords) for f in list_of_functions]
```

And print the new lambdas:

```
print "Make the call(s)...capitalized"
for f in list_of_functions:
    f('x')
```

Comment: but that does not answer the OP question of changing the function call within an inner function. i.e.: from `lambda x: foo(x,2)` to `lambda x: foo(x,2,3)`. You made the same mistake I made first time I read the OP's question ☺

Comment: No, see the comment `"# Modify args:"` - that's where I modify the args of each partial to add `'another_arg'` to the call, as specified by OP.

Comment: yup, but you're not answering the `capitalize=True` question ☺

Comment: You're right, because that was added as an edit to the original question. :-) But the same technique would work, just using the `partial.keywords` field.

Comment: nope, you're missing the point: the OP wants to keep `list_of_functions` code as is, but monkey patch each function in that list so the function call within the lambda gets a new argument. Neither did I understand it at first read, thanks to @ewcz who pointed it out to me.

Comment: I've added an update which addresses `capitalize=True`.

Comment: you're still missing the point! You're rewriting `list_of_functions` not monkey patching it. To quote the OP ***I would like to change list_of_functions to the following without having to re-write either list_of_functions above or simple_function***. Here, you're rewriting `list_of_functions` so you're not answering OP's question!